# Possible to access java application as a new process?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

To avoid memory problems within the JVM, I'm looking to create new processes for individual applets to be hosted within the main application.  Is there a way to do this similar to the following?

```
File file = new File("something.jar");
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", file.getAbsolutePath()).start();
// Somehow access process
Class<?> main = process.getMainClass();
```

Really just looking to have the ability to interact with another java process, even if it comes down to using reflection and such.

Comment: I'm just curious, what types of memory problems are you having?

Comment: Your machine has only a finite amount of accessible RAM. What do you perceive as the difference between partitioning it between multiple JVMs as opposed to increasing the amount of memory available to a single JVM?

Comment: No actual problems, just something similar to an OutOfMemoryException and I don't want to have the program launch a new process of itself with a JVM option to allocate more memory everytime a new applet is to be added.

Comment: @user1625108 Is there an issue with just launching it with more memory to begin with?

Comment: @Jason, No, but I don't want that to be the fix to the problem as more memory may need to be allocated if the user decides to add another applet to a viewer panel.

Comment: You can set a minimum and maximum heap size, though, and let the JVM and kernel manage it for you automatically. You'll never be able to use more memory than your machine has available. By spawning multiple JVMs, you will likely end up using more memory than having everything in a single JVM, as with multiple JVM's, unused space allocated to one JVM below it's minimum heap size cannot be used for another. With a single JVM, every applet will share memory as efficiently as possible. Essentially, spawning multiple JVMs is a wasteful way to accomplish the same thing as increasing max heap size.

Comment: (Not to mention separate JVMs will now have multiple copies of the same classes in RAM - one for each JVM, as well as any additional memory used in whatever method you decide to use to communicate between processes. That's a huge amount of unnecessary overhead per applet. Think of this in terms of how much actual system memory would be taken up total.)